# I had the fix navigation dropdown menu on hover as explained below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to change the background of nav item on dropdown when they are clicked. and also in screen resolution less than 992px the nav menu appears after clicking toggle button but thats not the problem, the problem is that the submenus in dropdown are in such a way that it is difficult to understand whoose submenu is displaying. I want to fix this.

this following is my html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index</title>
    <!-- bootstrap link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Custom css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
    <!-- JQuery3.2.1 -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <!-- Bootstrap  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNav" aria-controls="mainNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <!-- Trekking In Nepal -->
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      Trekking in Nepal
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Annapurna Region</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                  <li>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item submenuNav " href="#">Annapurna Circuit</a>
                                  </li>
                                  <li>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item submenuNav " href="#"> Annapurna Base Camp</a>
                                  </li>
                                  <li>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item submenuNav " href="#"> Upper Mustang</a>
                                  </li>
                            </ul>
                      </li>

                      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Everest Region</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                  <li>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item submenuNav " href="#">Everest Base Camp</a>
                                  </li>
                                  <li>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item submenuNav " href="#"> Jiri to Everest Base Camp</a>
                                  </li>
                                  <li>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item submenuNav " href="#"> Everest Three Pass</a>
                                  </li>
                            </ul>
                      </li>

                      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Langtang Region</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                  <li>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item submenuNav " href="#">Langtang Helambu</a>
                                  </li>
                                  <li>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item submenuNav " href="#"> Langtang Gosaikunda Lake</a>
                                  </li>
                                  <li>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item submenuNav " href="#">Langtang Valley</a>
                                  </li>
                            </ul>
                      </li>

                    </ul>
              </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- Custom js -->
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This following is what i write in custom.css

```
.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu{
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
}
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-submenu a::after {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: .8em;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: .1rem;
  margin-right: .1rem;
}
.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu{
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu{
    display: block;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
   .dropdown-submenu a::after {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: .8em;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
}
.submenuNav{
    opacity: 0.8;
    margin-right: 3px;
}
.submenuNav:hover{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(3px);
    transition: 0.4s all ease;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.dropdown-item{
    background-color: none !important;
    color: #007bff;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.dropdown-item:hover{
    background-color: none !important;
    color: #007bff;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.2s all ease;
}
.customNav{
    background-color: none !important;
    color:#007bff !important;
}
.navbar .navbar-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon{
 background-color: #007bff;
 }
```

This following is js file I write in custom.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".dropdown-item").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("customNav");
  });
});
```

Comment: Then go ahead - fix it. If you get stuck post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and someone might help you

Comment: now I've done that.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying:

> I want to change the background of nav item on dropdown when they are clicked

In this case, you need to change/set the `active` css selector for the `a` tags like so:

```html
.dropdown-submenu a:active { 
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

More info:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

Comment: P.S. just updated my snippet to work specifically with your code. No need for JavaScript in this case.

Comment: Note that setting the background-color to "none" isn't gonna work. You need to set a color such as white etc.

Comment: background-color is fixed after changing it to white. thank you.
I want the sub menu will appear on hover on large screens but on small screens like 'sm' view-port I want the submenu will appear only after clicking the navigation item. Need your help @WebDevBooster

Comment: On small touchscreen devices, it already does appear only after clicking/touching because there's no hover on touch devices. You can test that for yourself. Open Chrome dev tools, go into mobile device mode (i.e. click the icon that looks like a mobile phone) and your mouse cursor will turn into a circle indicating mobile mode/finger simulation. There you'll see that it's only on touch/click. There's no hover in that mode just like all touch devices.